# Invalid number error - [Error Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000] ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle, plsql

The 1st query from the below 2 queries is giving me [Error Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000] ORA-01722: invalid number error.
But when I limit the no of records as in the 2nd query then it is running fine.
Other than limiting the rows in the 2nd query, both the queries are identical.

```
SELECT b.first_name,
       b.last_name,
       b.device_derived,
       b.ios_version_group,
       b.add_date,
       FIRST_VALUE (b.add_date)
         OVER (PARTITION BY b.first_name, b.last_name, b.ios_version_group)
         AS first_date,
       LAST_VALUE (b.add_date)
         OVER (PARTITION BY b.first_name, b.last_name, b.ios_version_group)
         AS last_date
FROM   (SELECT a.first_name,
               a.last_name,
               a.os_version,
               a.device_type,
               a.device,
               a.add_date,
               a.device_derived,
               CASE
                 WHEN (    (   UPPER (a.device_derived) = 'IPHONE'
                            OR UPPER (a.device_derived) = 'IPAD')
                       AND TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (a.os_version, 1, 1)) > 4)
                 THEN
                   'iOS ' || SUBSTR (a.os_version, 1, 1)
                 ELSE
                   'Others'
               END
                 AS ios_version_group
        FROM   (SELECT first_name,
                       last_name,
                       os_version,
                       device_type,
                       device,
                       add_date,
                       CASE
                         WHEN UPPER (device_type) = 'ANDROID'
                         THEN
                           'Android'
                         WHEN    UPPER (device_type) = 'BB'
                              OR UPPER (device_type) = 'BLACKBERRY'
                         THEN
                           'Blackberry'
                         WHEN     UPPER (device_type) = 'IOS'
                              AND (   SUBSTR (UPPER (device), 1, 6) = 'IPHONE'
                                   OR SUBSTR (UPPER (device), 1, 4) = 'IPOD')
                         THEN
                           'iPhone'
                         WHEN     UPPER (device_type) = 'IOS'
                              AND (SUBSTR (UPPER (device), 1, 4) = 'IPAD')
                         THEN
                           'iPad'
                       END
                         AS device_derived
                FROM   vw_mobile_devices_all) a) b;



SELECT b.first_name,
       b.last_name,
       b.device_derived,
       b.ios_version_group,
       b.add_date,
       FIRST_VALUE (b.add_date)
         OVER (PARTITION BY b.first_name, b.last_name, b.ios_version_group)
         AS first_date,
       LAST_VALUE (b.add_date)
         OVER (PARTITION BY b.first_name, b.last_name, b.ios_version_group)
         AS last_date
FROM   (SELECT a.first_name,
               a.last_name,
               a.os_version,
               a.device_type,
               a.device,
               a.add_date,
               a.device_derived,
               CASE
                 WHEN (    (   UPPER (a.device_derived) = 'IPHONE'
                            OR UPPER (a.device_derived) = 'IPAD')
                       AND TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (a.os_version, 1, 1)) > 4)
                 THEN
                   'iOS ' || SUBSTR (a.os_version, 1, 1)
                 ELSE
                   'Others'
               END
                 AS ios_version_group
        FROM   (SELECT first_name,
                       last_name,
                       os_version,
                       device_type,
                       device,
                       add_date,
                       CASE
                         WHEN UPPER (device_type) = 'ANDROID'
                         THEN
                           'Android'
                         WHEN    UPPER (device_type) = 'BB'
                              OR UPPER (device_type) = 'BLACKBERRY'
                         THEN
                           'Blackberry'
                         WHEN     UPPER (device_type) = 'IOS'
                              AND (   SUBSTR (UPPER (device), 1, 6) = 'IPHONE'
                                   OR SUBSTR (UPPER (device), 1, 4) = 'IPOD')
                         THEN
                           'iPhone'
                         WHEN     UPPER (device_type) = 'IOS'
                              AND (SUBSTR (UPPER (device), 1, 4) = 'IPAD')
                         THEN
                           'iPad'
                       END
                         AS device_derived
                FROM   vw_mobile_devices_all) a) b
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 100;
```

Can somebody tell me why I am getting this error. Is there an efficient way to write this query?

Comment: Probably this code `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.OS_VERSION,1,1))` produces error, check your data. It is not number somewhere.

Comment: I checked the underlying data in the os_version field. All the values are like 1.0.1, 5.0.1,6.1.2 There is not a single value which don't have a number at the start. There are some leading spaces in some rows. I have handled that using SUBSTR (TRIM(a.os_version), 1, 1) Still I am getting [Error Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000] ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Please try: `select distinct substr(trim(os_version), 1, 1) from a`. I don't see other reasons for `ORA-01722` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You have `TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (a.os_version, 1, 1)` in your queries, so presumably you're hitting data that doesn't have a number at the start of the os_version, when you request more than 100 rows.

You need to check your data.

Comment: I checked the underlying data in the os_version field. All the values are like 1.0.1, 5.0.1,6.1.2
There is not a single value which don't have a number at the start. There are some leading spaces in some rows. I have handled that using SUBSTR (TRIM(a.os_version), 1, 1)
Still I am getting [Error Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: what does `select * from vw_mobile_devices_all a where translate(substr(trim(a.os_version), 1, 1), 'a1234567890', 'a') is not null;' give you?

Comment: Also, what are you going to do when an os_version is 2 or more digits long? You should alter your code to cope for that eventuality!

Comment: select * from vw_mobile_devices_all a where translate(substr(trim(a.os_version), 1, 1), 'a1234567890', 'a') is not null
this gives me a empty result set......
I just need the first digit of the records in os_version. I don't care for other digits.

Comment: So, when we're on ios10, are you still going to care only about the first digit? Also, if that query returned no rows, then in all probability, the view `vw_mobile_devices_all` has some to_number logic in it that's hitting data that isn't a number. You'd need to check the sql for the view and check the data in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to convert a non-numeric value with `TO_NUMBER`.

In the second query the first 100 rows seem not to result into `a.os_version` to a non-numeric value.

Try a simple select `vw_mobile_devices_all` to find the non-numeric os_version. Figure out how you can work around the problem. Maybe you can query the os_version differently.

Comment: I checked the underlying data in the os_version field. All the values are like 1.0.1, 5.0.1,6.1.2 There is not a single value which don't have a number at the start. There are some leading spaces in some rows. I have handled that using SUBSTR (TRIM(a.os_version), 1, 1) Still I am getting [Error Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000] ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Is `vw_mobile_devices_all` a view rather than a table? In that case it might be that the view is wrong. Can you post the view?